# How to manually instantiate objects using Ninject for MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject.web.mvc

How is it possible to use Ninject inside ASP.NET MVC 3 to instantiate objects manually? Something as

```
"NinjectObject".Resolve<IMyService>();
```

Thank you & regards

Answer (score 14):

It is better to inject dependencies instead of resolving them. Service Locator is an anti-pattern. You could for example use the following:

```
IMyService myService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IMyService>();
```

But please do not use it. That's an anti-pattern.

Dependency injection is the preferred way. You should have the constructor of the class that needs this dependency take an `IMyService` instead of having the class fetch this dependency.

Comment: That's what I am doing. I am creating a custom DependencyResolver based on Ninject, so I register all Interfaces with Ninject, but inside the custom DependencyResolver, I need to instantiate the interface with Ninject, that's what I need.

Comment: Guess i missed something here, Ninject registers itself as a custom DependencyResolver? I saw an example of a custom DependencyResolver based on MSFT Unity, where the code needed to resolve instances inside the custom DR.

Comment: Hi Darin, I had the case where I was implementing Start method of WebActivator, I needed an instance of a certain interface however, the class implementing WebActivator is Static and has no way to access an instance of that interface, what would be best way to do so? Thanks

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov You said doing this is an anti-pattern, is there any better way to get a service in a static method?

Comment: Thanks for answering how not to do it. But what if you need an instance from code? What is the answer?