# Ninject inject a service interface in a web service

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ninject

I have a web service in my project that I use to return json data to ajax calls.

Injecting my ClientService works fine on regular pages but how do I get it to work in the Web Service?

NinjectWebCommon.cs:

```
 private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IClientService>().To<ClientService>();
        }
```

Default.aspx.cs: works!

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
 [Inject]
        public IClientService clientService { get; set; }
```

MyWebservice.asmx: NullReferenceException (clientService is null)

```
 public class MyWebService: System.Web.Services.WebService
    {     
        [Inject]
        public IClientService clientService { get; set; } 


 [WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public MyObject GetClients(int id)
        {
            var list = clientService.GetClients(id);
```

Comment: Have you looked at any of the samples to see if there is an example of a WebService being Injected?

Comment: The only examples I can find are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765424/how-to-manually-instantiate-objects-using-ninject-for-mvc-3. Although it seems that the DependencyResolver class doesn't exist in the latest version of ninject?

Comment: I mean on github.com/ninject - I havent looked but I'd be surprised if there isnt an asmx somewhere. Note that the DependencyResolver stuff is in a different NuGet package (again, see an MVC sample)

Comment: Have you solved this. I really need this and cant get it to work...

Comment: Nope I haven't - please post a solution if you manage to find one!

Comment: i run into same issue .. any luck with this?

Comment: @LaurenceNyein haven't looked at this in ages, but don't think I had any luck or I would have posted the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved this problem. I changed MyWebService class to derive from `Ninject.Web.WebServiceBase`:

```
public class MyWebService: WebServiceBase
```

Comment: If you using NinjectWebCommon, maybe you need Install-Package Ninject.Web and remove NinjectWeb.cs auto created

Answer (score 1):

I run on the same problem. Took me a while to figure it out.
My solution to this problem is adding statatic Ninject instantiation of **Kernel** in **Global.asax** :

```
  public class Global : NinjectHttpApplication 
    {
        private static Ninject.IKernel kernel = new Ninject.StandardKernel();

        protected override Ninject.IKernel CreateKernel()
        {

            //Business TI
            kernel.Bind<IYourService>().To<YourService>();

            return kernel;
        }
}
```

What enables to get it directly from singleton(public) or which solution I choosed, by accesing **NinjectHttpApplication's context** :
//in webservice parameterless constructor

```
yourService = ((NinjectHttpApplication)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance).Kernel.Get<IPublicationService>();
```

This is the solution for working with legacy asmx web service, putting aside